# Select all checkbox redux form

Tags: material-ui, redux-form

I want to check/ uncheck all checkboxes the moment I select Check All but can't make it work. I'm using material-ui components and redux-form. my plan is to grab checkAll field value using formValueSelector API and set checkbox A and B value based of that. Also tried using value prop but no luck still.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Field, reduxForm, formValueSelector } from 'redux-form';
import { Checkbox } from 'redux-form-material-ui';

let Form = (props) => {

return (
    <form>

      <Field name="checkAll" id="checkAll" label="Check All" component={ Checkbox } />

      <Field name="a" label="A" component={ Checkbox } checked={ props.checkAll } />

      <Field name="b" label="B" component={ Checkbox } checked={ props.checkAll } />

    </form>
  );
};

Form = reduxForm({
  form: 'Form'
})(AddReturnModal);

// Decorate with connect to read form values
const selector = formValueSelector('Form'); // <-- same as form name
Form = connect(
 (state) => {
    const checkAll = selector(state, 'checkAll');

    return {
      checkAll
    };
  }
)(Form);

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `change` method. [From docs:](http://redux-form.com/6.2.0/docs/api/Props.md/)

> **change(field:String, value:any) : Function**
>
> Changes the value of a field in the Redux store. This is a bound action creator, so it returns nothing.

The only solution I see is to loop over the list of checkboxes and call `change(checkboxName, value)` on them.

Answer (score 0):

@notgiorgi is right, to select all checkboxes, you can do this:

```
selectAll = () => {
  const { change } = this.props

  ['a', 'b'].forEach((field) => change(field, true))
}
```

If you wanted a toggle, you might easily/cheaply/ignorantly be able to keep a rough reference to the selectAll state:

```
selectAllValue = false

selectAll = () => {
  const { change } = this.props

  ['a', 'b'].forEach((field) => change(field, this.selectAllValue))

  // toggle select all to select none
  this.selectAllValue = !this.selectAllValue
}
```